# IllegalStateException on Google Cloud Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to write a simple vanilla collaborative filtering application, running on Google Cloud Dataproc.
The Data is located in BigQuery.
I have implemented this according to this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-sparkml

Now the problem is that when running this (slightly modified) example I get an IllegalStateException. More specifically here is the stacktrace:

```
17/09/25 10:55:37 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/af84ad68-0259-4ca1-b464-a118a96f0742/marketing-pages-collaborative-filtering.py", line 109, in <module>
compute_recommendations()
File "/tmp/af84ad68-0259-4ca1-b464-a118a96f0742/marketing-pages-collaborative-filtering.py", line 59, in compute_recommendations
conf=conf)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 646, in newAPIHadoopRDD
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, marketing-pages-collaborative-filtering-w-1.c.dg-dev-personalization.internal): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found known file 'data-000000000002.json' with index 2, which isn't less than or equal to than endFileNumber 1!
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.DynamicFileListRecordReader.setEndFileMarkerFile(DynamicFileListRecordReader.java:327)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.DynamicFileListRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DynamicFileListRecordReader.java:177)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1324)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1873)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1886)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1298)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$.pairRDDToPython(SerDeUtil.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala:582)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found known file 'data-000000000002.json' with index 2, which isn't less than or equal to than endFileNumber 1!
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.DynamicFileListRecordReader.setEndFileMarkerFile(DynamicFileListRecordReader.java:327)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.DynamicFileListRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DynamicFileListRecordReader.java:177)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1324)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

17/09/25 10:55:37 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.ServerConnector: Stopped ServerConnector@1dfdb336{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4040}
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.pyspark) Job [af84ad68-0259-4ca1-b464-a118a96f0742] entered state [ERROR] while waiting for [DONE].
```

I think I have identified the problem, but I cannot find the cause of the problem. The relevant code snippet is this:

```
table_rdd = spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    "com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable",
    "com.google.gson.JsonObject",
    conf=conf)

table_json = table_rdd.map(lambda x: x[1])
visit_data = sparkSession.read.json(table_json)
```

First I create the RDD according to the tutorial from Google. The next step is to extract the JSON elements from the RDD, and this then is read into a table, that we can query.
The stacktrace shows that the exception happens when assigning conf, but the code works until I call `sparkSession.read.json(table_json)` because as I understood it spark works lazily and only then tries to access the actual JSON files that were exported from BigQuery.

Now the problem is that Spark finds more JSON files than there should be.
According to this [comment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/38c73bdfc39da09c5922903dbe0366d70482e991/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/ShardedExportToCloudStorage.java#L44) in the code of the BigQuery Hadoop Library, even if everything fits into one shard, the minimum is two, such that BigQuery recognizes the export as such. Also it says there that it generates a so called end-marker file, which as far as I can say, is just an empty JSON file.

But when running the code the export that is generated by BigQuery has more than the 2 necessary files (1 containing data and 1 as the end-marker). It generates up to 5 JSON files, that sometimes contain just 1 or 2 rows from BigQuery.

I am pretty sure that this is the problem, that the export somehow is wrong. But I cannot find out why this happens and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I tried something else. I deleted the table in BigQuery and populated it again from scratch. This solved the problem with the export. There are only two files now. But I think the problem still persists. I will try adding some rows via Cloud Functions (which would happen in my application) and then update on the behaviour.

UPDATE 2:

So after waiting a day and adding some rows via streaming inserts using a Cloud Function, the issue happens again. Somehow the exports are partitioned by day. That would not be a problem if each day gets its own shard, but this does not happen unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have a BigQuery jobid you can share? You can also contact the google team directly at dataproc-feedback@google.com to share your project id. Your assessment is correct that there shouldn't ever be any files numbered after the "end-marker" zero-length file. Are you using BigQuery "streaming inserts" to add rows, or are you adding with heavyweight "load" jobs?

Comment: @DennisHuo Thank you for the response. I have already contacted the google team, but they take a lot of time to process this. To insert we use streaming inserts, over Cloud Functions. Somehow the additional files only appear if we wait for one day and add additional rows.

Comment: I'm not sure if running queries against BQ to build ML systems is a good approach. Here in [this project](https://github.com/WillianFuks/PySpark-RecSys) I created you can see that I have some exporters that run queries in BQ and export results to GCS and then I read these in spark. Never had any issue and it works quite fast (and also it avoids running queries all the time which costs money, this approach runs just once). Coincidentally it also implements a recommender system but using DIMSUM algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in BigQuery (that it returns the output file count statistics that does not include the zero-record file). The fix for this issue has been submitted, and its rollout will complete in about a week.

In the meantime, a workaround of the issue is maybe set the flag `"mapred.bq.input.sharded.export.enable"` (a.k.a. `ENABLE_SHARDED_EXPORT_KEY`) to false in your hadoop config when configuring your DataProc job.

**UPDATE:**
As of today Oct 6 2017, the fix is now 100% rolled out on BigQuery.

Comment: Is there a ticket or bug report for this somewhere? I am encountering this issue when trying to use the BigQuery connector with PySpark on DataProc to read data from a table.

Comment: We don't have a public bug report filed yet, but if you're still seeing this error it might be from a corner case that would yield the same error once the table gets to a certain state. We have an internal bug tracking this, but feel free to file a bug report to BigQuery if you think that's useful. In the meantime, you can use the method suggested in the answer to get unblocked. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please tell how to set that flag to false?

Comment: I think that depends on which language/library you're using. If you're following the same tutorial as the original question (https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-sparkml), then look for this part in the code sample:

    conf = {
        "mapred.bq.project.id": project,
        ...
    }

and add another key "mapred.bq.input.sharded.export.enable" with "false" as value to the dictionary should do the job.